# jquery dropdown working in all browsers but IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, cufon

Earlier in the day I had some free time and was like hey I'm going to do a cool drop down menu that people can use. I started creating it and everything went fine until i was done and checking it in all browsers. I noticed on hover the drop down doesn't appear at all. If i change it from display:none to block it shows fine but it seems the jquery isn't doing anything. I also read around and saw some people post problems a little similar that were resolved by adding position:relative or filter:inherit but i couldn't seem to get that working no matter what element i put it on. I was wondering if anyone could help me because I'm pretty stumbled

http://imstillreallybored.com/freebies/dropdown/

Comment: Somewhat interestingly, it works reasonably well in IE8 (which appears to have a slight problem with padding on the LIs), the position of the menu itself has shifted to the top of the window in IE7 (plus there's a strange shadow effect), and in IE9 the dropdown displays beautifully... Except the text doesn't appear. This is on Windows 7.

Comment: I think it is clear the problem is with cufon.  I would look and see what the latest release supports -- you might need to post a bug report with them.  (to prove this, take cufon out and see if you can get it to work in the min case.)

Comment: it doesn't work in IE8 or IE9 for me at all 0.0.  i just figured most people user developer tools on some browser and can look at the live code easily being it's all client side. I'll try messing with cufon i was using @font-face at first but the aliasing is just horrible for some browsers - it looked bold.

EDIT: Just got updated version font is showing now i just see the padding problem like mentioned above

Comment: If you have IE9, you have the same developer tools I have. Hit F12 to see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is the Cufon plugin:

http://jfcoder.com/test/cufon.html

Once I remove this from the picture, the dropdown works reasonably well (with the padding issue still a problem, but that can be fixed).

Comment: As I expected.  Cufon is just not as production ready as jQuery.